# Analyzing crash - translate disassembly instructions to C++ equivalent

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, crash

I'm attempting to debug a crash. `(ACCESS_VIOLATION)`

Below is a disassembly snippet. I marked the line that the exception occurs on.
**What instruction does it correspond to in the actual C++ code shown below it?**

Disassembly:

```
420: for( Uint32 i = 0; i < m_children.size(); ++i){
    06A923D3 8B 46 0C             mov         eax,dword ptr [esi+0Ch]  
    06A923D6 57                   push        edi  
    06A923D7 33 FF                xor         edi,edi  
--> 06A923D9 39 38                cmp         dword ptr [eax],edi  
    06A923DB 76 59                jbe         ICategoryNode::iterate+66h (6A92436h)  
    06A923DD 53                   push        ebx  
    06A923DE 55                   push        ebp  
    06A923DF 8B 2D 04 60 B0 06    mov         ebp,dword ptr [__imp_::AssertionFailure::logAssert (6B06004h)]  
    06A923E5 33 DB                xor         ebx,ebx  
421: bool keepGoing = CategoryImp::recursiveIterator(handler, *m_children[i]);
```

Actual C++ code:

```
void ICategoryNode::iterate(ICategoryHandler& handler) const {
    for(Uint32 i = 0; i < m_children.size(); ++i) {
        bool keepGoing = CategoryImp::recursiveIterator(handler, *m_children[i]);
        if(!keepGoing)
            return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like `cmp dword ptr [eax],edi` corresponds to the < size() check - note that the dereference of the size member of `m_children` is inlined into the less-than check.

Most likely, your `this` pointer is invalid. You may have called `ICategoryNode::iterate` on a null pointer, or a deleted object or something (if `eax` has a very low value, it's probably a null pointer - but in any case, check the stack frame above this, you should be able to get the bad address of the object being called).

Comment: Are you implying that `this` must be null because using `m_children` causes the exception? I edited the code to make clear the fact that it's already entered the member function (thus `this` was valid).

Comment: No. I mean `this` is invalid. ie, you called `ptr->iterate(something)`, where `ptr` was NULL, or uninitialized, or already deleted, or otherwise invalid. m_children is not a pointer, so it cannot be NULL.

Comment: @dominus: Why do you claim that `this` must be valid just because you entered the member function? Is the member function virtual? If not, you have no reason to trust your `this` pointer. I agree with bdonlan.

Comment: I've debugged all kinds of interesting bugs where `this` became invalid _halfway through_ the function - never assume `this` is valid just because you made it into the function, even if it _is_ virtual!